# Restful route helpers using '.' instead of '/' in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

My path helpers (like data_path, users_path) are now translating itself to use '.' instead of '/'.

For example, data_path(@data) translates to:

```
data.%23<datareport:0x7fcaba0c2970>
```

instead of '/data/id'.

My routes look like:

```
  map.resources :data
```

Comment: It is possible to add new pluralization exceptions. I don't know if that will help for routes, though. http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html The singular of data is 'datum', if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the resources must be in plural form. As far as i see, in rails, 'data'.pluralize is 'datas'. You may also check out this: [Ruby on rails path helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847491/ruby-on-rails-path-helpers)

Comment: See this answer, which is a bit more descriptive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes

Answer (score 1):

@cristian is right. If you are using `:data` instead of `:datas` then you should define your route to be `map.resource :data`

But the plural form is `map.resources :datas`