# Path helpers generate paths with dots instead of slashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
resources :message_threads
```

When I call:

```
message_threads_path(1)
```

I get:

```
/message_threads.1
```

Why is this? My other resources work fine. Am I not pluralizing this correctly or something?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Yes, this is a pluralization error.

By passing the ID 1, I assume that you wish to display a single record.

So you need to use the singular 'message_thread':

```
message_thread_path(1)
```

Which will yield:

```
http://localhost:3000/message_threads/1
```

Comment: Heh. It happens to us all; frequently. Probably won't be the last time you see this error!

Comment: I'm getting this very same error with a named route I created and I'm not pluralizing it. What would be the fix there?

Comment: @kakubei, check your routes file. Are you calling `resources :my_model` or `resources :my_models`? (You need to pluralize in the routes file.)

Comment: All my routes are pluralized.

Comment: Just gone 5pm, was about to bash my head against the keyboard, this was it. Thanks man.

Comment: I am using resources :quizzes, and see this in rake routes, api_quizzes POST   /api/quizzes(.:format)                            api/v1/quizzes#create {:format=>"json"}

Are you saying that the 'rake routes' command has a bug in it?

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes this also is when you don't provide an :as parameter in your route:

```
delete "delete/:id" => "home#delete"
```

Changed to:

```
delete "delete/:id" => "home#delete", as: :delete
```

(ignore the odd example, just happened to be something we just ran into for an internal app we're building)

Comment: This worked for me. Specifying **:as** gave me a name that I could append "_path" to and have Rails know what the hell I was asking for in link_to.

Originally, when my routes file had:

`match "/xyz/show/:project_id" => "xyz#show_project", :via => [:get]`

my view markup:

`<%= link_to "Show Details", xyz_show_path(@project) %>`

kept producing: `http://localhost:3000/xyz/show.1`

Changing the routes file to:

`match "/xyz/show/:project_id" => "xyz#show_project", :via => [:get], :as => "show"`

allowed:

`<%= link_to "Show Details", show_path(@project) %>`

to work.

Answer (score 1):

Other folks that land here might be in this situation:

If you have a singular resource declared in your `routes.rb`:

```rb
resource :map
```

You don't need to pass an object to `map_path`. Attempting to call `map_path(map)` will result in similar behavior (i.e. a URL like `map.12`).