# Rails routing using to_param period added - Pluralization Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've created a model that I'm overriding the primary key on:

`set_primary_key :SONumber`

I'm also using `to_param`

```
def to_param
    self.SONumber
end
```

My route for this model is as follows:

```
resources :sales_orders
```

In the view when linking to show an individual record:

```
=link_to 'Open', sales_orders_path(so)
```

It's generating links with periods in them instead of slashes i.e.:

```
.../sales_orders.1234  instead of .../sales_orders/1234
```

What am I missing here? Did I do something wrong?

EDIT:
From my routes:

```
sales_order GET    /sales_orders/:id(.:format)       sales_orders#show
```

EDIT 2:
Reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes), I can only assume I have a pluralization error, however, if I switch the view to:

```
=link_to 'Open', sales_order_path(so)
```

I get no route matches... I'd rather not manually define the route if there's a better way

Comment: I'd try using lowercase letters as primary_key attribute since strings that start with uppercase letters are considered constants in ruby, that may cause some conflict there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
= link_to 'Open', sale_order_path(so) # sale instead of sales
```

`sales_order_path(so)` generates the path for index action with `so.SONumber` as format.

Take a look at this Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

Comment: sales_orders_path generates a path to the index, after restarting the server,=link_to 'Open', sales_order_path(so) ended up working!