# Rails dot instead of slash in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my routes.rb I have:

```
get "projects/:category_id" => "projects#index"
```

When I write `projects_path(1)` the generated URL is `/projects.1` instead of `/projects/1`. Do you know why this is happening?
Here is the output of `rake routes`:

```
 GET /projects/:category_id(.:format) projects#index
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails creating malformed routes with dots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033853/rails-creating-malformed-routes-with-dots)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path helpers generate paths with dots instead of slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`projects_path` is the index, which only takes one argument: the format.  You want `project_path(1)`

Comment: LOL. This was killing me. Thanks.