# Rails app ending in dot id versus slash, how to get slash route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  resources :users, except: [ :delete ] do
    resources :bookings, except: [ :delete ]
    resources :reviews, except: [ :edit, :update, :delete ]
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I'm getting "/users/1/bookings.3" but I want "/users/1/bookings/3". What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16264981/544825

Comment: You're probably doing `users_bookings_path(user, booking)` instead of `users_booking_path(user, booking)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `user_bookings_path(user, booking)`.