# Why is there a . instead of a / in my URL path in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed Devise (called members) and have set up some custom routes so that I can spit out all the members and allow them to have their own page (/memebers/ and /members/:id/)

However in my view file for the members index when passing the route members_path(member_id) it is outputting members.1 instead of members/1

Code below:
index view:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
<tr>
<td><%= link_to member.name, members_path(member.id) %></td>
<td><%= member.email %></td>
<td><%= member.id %></td>
<td><%= member.admin %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :members
match 'members/' => 'members#index'
match 'members/:id' => 'members#show'
```

Members Controller:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @members = Member.all
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @student } 
   end 
  end

  def show
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Rake Routes:

```
members        /members(.:format)               members#index
               /members/:id(.:format)           members#show
```

Any help? Cheers :)

Comment: May help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes

Comment: @Jimbo no luck I'm afraid. :(

Comment: use restful resources instead, so you will get path helpers to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add

```
, as: :show_member
```

so in my routes file I had to define a path for that

```
match 'members/:id/' => 'members#show', as: :show_member
```

and adding this in the index view file:

```
show_member_path(member)
```

and rake routes is now:

```
members GET    /members(.:format)               members#index
show_member GET    /members/:id(.:format)           members#show
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the helper method you are looking for. `members_path` creates a path to `members#index` and takes `format` as its only argument.

The helper that links to `members#show` is `member_path`. Although, it's not automatically created by `match`:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :members, only: [:index, :show]
# Remove `only` to get the remaining restful routes

# and in your view:
<%= link_to member.name, member_path(member.id) %>
```

You can also just pass in the member itself and `link_to` will automatically call `to_param`, which returns `id` by default:

```
<%= link_to member.name, member_path(member) %>
```

Alternatively, you can just pass in your member directly with no path helper:

```
<%= link_to member.name, member %>
```

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html