# Rails 4 issue: No route matches [PATCH] "/book.17"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I am working on an edit page which works. However, when I click the save button to save the changes I make, in rails 4, I get the following message: No route matches [PATCH] "/book.17" Any advice on how to fix this? I have been researching for a while and believe that it has something to do with my routes and not directing to the right page. Just not sure how I should change it. I have tried using patch/put instead of get for my edit action or putting patch 'books#update' to update but get the same error message. Any help will be appreciated! Here is the code:

Controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

def new
 #@book = Book.all
 @book = Book.new 
 @authors = Author.all
end

def edit 
  @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @authors = Author.all
end 

def update 
 @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
   flash[:success] = "Book Updated!"
   redirect_to @book
  else
      render 'edit'
  end 
end
```

Routes Page:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'welcome#index'

get 'author' => 'authors#new'

get 'name' => 'authors#show'

get 'book' => 'books#new'

get 'show' => 'books#show'

patch 'edit' => 'books#update'

resources :authors

resources :books
```

Edit Page:

```
<div class="move">
<h1>Update a book entry</h2>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

<%= form_for(@book)  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form' %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :pub_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :pub_date, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :publisher %>
    <%= f.text_field :publisher, class: 'form-control' %><br />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select(:author_id, @authors.collect {|a| 
   [ a.name, a.id ]}, {:include_blank => 'Please select an author'}, 
   class: "form-control") %><br />
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Save Changes', class: "btn btn-primary" %> 

  <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Finally, my rake routes:

```
Rake routes
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
   root GET    /                           welcome#index
 author GET    /author(.:format)           authors#new
   name GET    /name(.:format)             authors#show
   book GET    /book(.:format)             books#new
   show GET    /show(.:format)             books#show
   edit GET    /edit(.:format)             books#edit
  books GET    /books(.:format)            books#index
        POST   /books(.:format)            books#create
  new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)        books#new
  edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)   books#edit
        GET    /books/:id(.:format)        books#show
        PATCH  /books/:id(.:format)        books#update
        PUT    /books/:id(.:format)        books#update
        DELETE /books/:id(.:format)        books#destroy
  authors GET    /authors(.:format)          authors#index
        POST   /authors(.:format)          authors#create
  new_author GET    /authors/new(.:format)      authors#new
  edit_author GET    /authors/:id/edit(.:format) authors#edit
        GET    /authors/:id(.:format)      authors#show
        PATCH  /authors/:id(.:format)      authors#update
        PUT    /authors/:id(.:format)      authors#update
        DELETE /authors/:id(.:format)      authors#destroy
```

Here is what my log is saying:

Started PATCH "/book.18" for ::1 at 2015-08-15 16:32:10 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/book.18"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'

Comment: Why do you have all of those extra routes? You should be good with just the `resources :authors` and `resources :books`.

Comment: Also, what is your web console saying when you make the request that results in that error. It looks like it is saving and it should redirect to `/books/17`, but it is getting `/book.17`. Add your console output to the question.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `Book.find_by_id(params[:id])`, you can just say `Book.find(params[:id])`. `find` by itself implies `id`. The other forms of `find_by_....` are deprecated in favor of `find_by(column_name: 'something')`.

Comment: I added my log and changed the Book.find_by_id(params[:id]) to Book.find(params[:id]). I also noticed that it is going after /book.17 vice /book/17. Any other help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the route

```
     patch 'edit' => 'books#update'
```

to

```
     patch '/book.:id/' => 'books#update'
```

it solves the problem

Comment: Done but same error of "No route matches [PATCH] "/book.17"

Comment: Try putting this in the route.rb file patch "/books/:id" => "books#update"

Comment: placed the following into route.rb:  patch "/books/:id" => "books#update" and still get the error message: No route matches [PATCH] "/book.17"

Comment: Can you upload the code to github so I can take a look?

Comment: Yes, it is there. My GitHub name is ravenusmc and file is called teach_2

Comment: Thank you! I have never seen '/book.:id/' used and just would need to understand that! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Here you have a solution to change the dot into a slash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes

Comment: You shouldn't have to hack it like this. There is something wrong with your code and your routes.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of those redundant routes, they are just going to mess you up. Rails processes the routes.rb file from the top down, so the order can be screwing you up when you have routes that are basically overriding each other. Just use:

```
resources :books
resources :authors
```

This should give you a `rake:routes` output like:

```
books_path      GET /books(.:format)    books#index
                POST    /books(.:format)    books#create
new_book_path   GET /books/new(.:format)    books#new
edit_book_path  GET /books/:id/edit(.:format)   books#edit
book_path       GET /books/:id(.:format)    books#show
                PATCH   /books/:id(.:format)    books#update
                PUT /books/:id(.:format)    books#update
                DELETE  /books/:id(.:format)    books#destroy
```

Controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# the above will DRY up your code with a callback

def new
 #@book = Book.all
 @book = Book.new 
 @authors = Author.all
end

def edit 
  @authors = Author.all
end 

def update 
  if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
   flash[:success] = "Book Updated!"
   redirect_to @book
  else
  render 'edit'
  end

private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some complicated solutions...

The clue is the malformed url "/book.17" which should read /books/17. You're messing up the rails default url generator up with your routes file entry

```
patch 'edit' => 'books#update'
```

because

```
resources :books
```

should already give you an update route. But since it is defined below (after) your manually entered patch route... that's the one that wins so now this line won't work properly in your form for helper. See [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for) for more information

```
form_for(@user)
```

Also note the "edit" route in rails is the one that renders the edit view. Its not the one that the edit form submits to, that's the update action. You're kind of trying to do both with

```
patch 'edit' => 'books#update'
```

You probably want the book route because you're going OCD on the url scheme, i.e. its only one "book" so url shouldn't say "books". Hold off on that thinking. My advice is until you get the hang of rails better don't fight the conventions, plural routes, etc. Eventually it'll be a piece of cake, but you have a lot more to worry about learning so don't waste your time on the routing conventions. Just drink the kool-aid for a bit and learn the framework.

If you really must have it [review this section of the rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).