# Route using dot rather than / in rails DELETE method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, erb

The delete button I have in my rails app returns the following error :

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/requests.3"
```

I'm not sure why.

Here is the button link in the request view (using bootstrap 3) :

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>'.html_safe,
    requests_path(request), method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },  class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

and in routes I have :

```
delete 'requests/:id' => 'requests#destroy'
```

and in the controller I have

```
def destroy
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  @request.destroy
  redirect_to action: 'index', status: 303
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path helpers generate paths with dots instead of slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes)

Comment: Following that thread lead to changing `requests_path` to `request_path` which led to an `undefined method \`request_path\` ` error. @KieranE

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured to work was to manually specify the path in the `<%= link_to` tag

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>'.html_safe,
"/requests/#{request.id}/destroy", method: :delete, 
data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },  class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

and that seemed to work.